# Does 'with' in the second sentence introduce a nuance of any kind?

Tags: grammar

Please give me a baseball bat to hit the ball.

Please give me a baseball bat to hit the ball with.

Comment: It makes the sentence sound more polished. Acceptability here will probably be seen differently by different native speakers; some may still be influenced by the 'don't end a sentence with a preposition' shibboleth.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it does. It sounds more normal, casual and typical of someone who knows what a ball is and how to hit it with a bat. You would never go with "Give me a bat with which to hit this ball" but that is how to keep the preposition in its place. The first sentence sounds just casual enough to go by without a problem. The only nuance you'd be adding is an unpleasant attention to the "with". Strike out.